# View folder size on Dropbox

Tags: dropbox

Is there a way to view the size of a folder on the Dropbox web?

I tried using the instructions from Dropbox [here](https://help.dropbox.com/desktop-web/sort-files), but they seem to be outdated and do not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display the size of a folder on dropbox.com:

- go to **https://www.dropbox.com/**
- click on **Files**
- click on column header
- select **Size**
- select folder you are interested in by enabling checkbox
- click on **Calculate size** in the right sidebar
- wait for calculation
- done

[image: 0]